# jquery context menu plugin details

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I saw the below which uses jquery contextMenu.

`JET`

```
$(function() {
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-one', 
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var m = "clicked: " + key;
            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
        },
        items: {
            "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
            "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
           copy: {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
            "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
            "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
            "sep1": "---------",
            "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: function(){
                return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
            }}
        }
    });

    $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e){
        console.log('clicked', this);
    })    
});
```

`JET`

I referred to [this](https://github.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu) link to understand the details:

1. is context menu functionality part of jquery?
2. or jQuery-contextMenu  is altogether a different third party library. Can you please clarify?
3. Does it need a license?

Comment: It's a 3rd party library. That's why it's in that separate Github site. jQuery has its own repository. So if you want to use it, you need to include that extra library in your page. There's a demo and documentation linked right there from the Github page. The page also tells you what the license is (MIT). Read it again, more carefully.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, so Jquery UI Context menu is separate Library (which is MIT Licensed) , and doesnt come by default with JqueryUI right?

Comment: Yes. All of that information is in the github page.

Comment: P.S. It's not called jQueryUI-Context menu. It's called jQuery-Context menu. It has nothing to do with the jQueryUI project. It requires regular jQuery in order to work, that's all. (It says you can also use jQueryUI position with it, but that it's not essential. Again, it's all there, all you have to do is read...not sure why you are confused exactly.)

Comment: No problem...but all you had to do was just read the page properly.

Answer (score 0):

All the information you've asked about is mentioned directly in, or is clear from, the link you provided: https://github.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu

1. It's not a core part of jQuery. jQuery has a different repository for its core code.
2. This contextMenu is a separate plugin which depends on jQuery. It can also *optionally* depend on jQueryUI Position, which again is a separate library.
3. It is released under the MIT license. This is a permissive license. You don't need to pay to use the plugin.

Comment: I modified my query , looks like it didnt reflect properly. ill post a new one. Thanks a lot for your responce i already understood it from your prev respoce itself. I will post a new query reg my issue with using jquery context menu

Comment: Actually I rolled your changes back because you turned it very different question. You shouldn't radically change your question half-way through. It's right to ask a new one. Therefore I changed it back to what you asked originally. What I've posted here answers the original question. I've just posted this as a formal answer so it can be formally marked as accepted (which comments can't) and others can vote on it, if they wish.

Comment: P.S. When you ask your new question, I advise you to provide more details than simply saying "it doesn't work". That's not a technical description of your problem. Describe the precise behaviour of the code when you try to run it, including any errors messages seen in the browser's Console, or elsewhere. Make sure to include information of the debugging you have done (and make sure you have actually _done_ some debugging with the built-in debugger in your browser), and ensure that what you show us is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)